# MapMvcAttributeRoutes com PagedList.MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, route

Estou usando o `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` para decorar minhas Actions com a Url que desejo que apareça no navegador, e tem dado muito certo, porém, ao usar com o `PagedList`  venho tendo um problema que não consigo resolver.

abaixo segue o código do meu controller:

```
    [Route("sala-de-impresa/noticias/{page?}")]
    public ActionResult Noticia(int? page)
    {
        var model = _ctx.Noticias.Include("Categoria").Where(n => n.Status && n.DataPublicacao <= DateTime.Now).OrderByDescending(n => n.NoticiaId);

        const int pageSize = 20;
        var pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(model.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }
```

Aqui o código da View que faz a paginação:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Noticia", new { page, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }), PagedListRenderOptions.OnlyShowFivePagesAtATime)
```

Para a página Inicial a Url e acessada sem problemas,

Ex: localhost:xxxx/sala-de-impresa/noticias

Mas ao tentar avançar a paginação para a página 2 por Exemplo:

localhost:xxxx/sala-de-impresa/noticias/2

recebo o erro:

```
Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'.

Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. This can happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested URL.

The request has found the following matching controller types: 
WP_AMERON.Controllers.NoticiaController
WP_AMERON.Controllers.SalaImprensaController

Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código. 

Detalhes da Exceção: System.InvalidOperationException: Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. This can happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested URL.

The request has found the following matching controller types: 
WP_AMERON.Controllers.NoticiaController
WP_AMERON.Controllers.SalaImprensaController

Erro de Origem: 

Exceção sem tratamento foi gerada durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. As informações relacionadas à origem e ao local da exceção podem ser identificadas usando-se o rastreamento de pilha de exceção abaixo.

Rastreamento de Pilha: 


[InvalidOperationException: Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. This can happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested URL.

The request has found the following matching controller types: 
WP_AMERON.Controllers.NoticiaController
WP_AMERON.Controllers.SalaImprensaController]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerTypeFromDirectRoute(RouteData routeData) +373
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerType(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +141
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory.GetControllerSessionBehavior(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.GetSessionStateBehavior(RequestContext requestContext) +131
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext) +33
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.System.Web.Routing.IRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase context) +9767524
   System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.OnApplicationPostResolveRequestCache(Object sender, EventArgs e) +82
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69

Informações sobre a Versão: Microsoft .NET Framework Versão:4.0.30319; Versão do ASP.NET:4.0.30319.33440
```

Porém se eu editar a Url e colocar da seguinte maneira:

localhost:xxxx/sala-de-impresa/noticias?page=2

A paginação funciona normalmente.

**EDIT:**

Código do Controller Noticia e SalaImpresa

```
public class SalaImprensaController : Controller
    {
        readonly AmeronContext _ctx = new AmeronContext();

        [Route("sala-de-impresa/noticias/{page?}")]
        public ActionResult Noticia(int? page)
        {
            var model = _ctx.Noticias.Include("Categoria").Where(n => n.Status && n.DataPublicacao <= DateTime.Now).OrderByDescending(n => n.NoticiaId);

            const int pageSize = 20;
            var pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View(model.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }

        [Route("sala-de-impresa/videos")]
        public ActionResult Videos(int? page)
        {
            var model = _ctx.Videos.ToList().OrderByDescending(n => n.VideoId).ToList();

            const int pageSize = 9;
            var pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View(model.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }

        [Route("sala-de-impresa/galerias/{page?}")]
        public ActionResult Galerias(int? page)
        {
            var model = _ctx.Galerias.ToList().OrderByDescending(n => n.GaleriaId).ToList();

            const int pageSize = 9;
            var pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View(model.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }
    }




public class NoticiaController : Controller
    {
        readonly AmeronContext _ctx = new AmeronContext();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult CarouselNoticias()
        {
            var model = _ctx.Noticias.Include("Categoria").Where(n => n.Status && n.DataPublicacao <= DateTime.Now && n.Destaque).OrderByDescending(n => n.NoticiaId);
            return PartialView("_Carroussel", model);
        }

        public ActionResult Noticias()
        {
            var model = _ctx.Noticias.Include("Categoria").Where(n => n.Status && n.DataPublicacao <= DateTime.Now && n.Destaque == false).OrderByDescending(n => n.NoticiaId);
            return PartialView("_Noticias", model);
        }

        [Route("{categoria}/{id}/{titulo}")]
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var noticia = _ctx.Noticias.Include("Categoria").FirstOrDefault(n => n.NoticiaId == id);

            if (noticia == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("NotFound");
            }

            if (noticia.ViewNumber == null)
            {
                noticia.ViewNumber = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                noticia.ViewNumber++;
            }

            _ctx.Entry(noticia).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _ctx.SaveChanges();

            var categoria = noticia.Categoria.Nome;
            var widget = _ctx.Noticias.Include("Categoria").ToList().Where(n => n.Categoria.Nome == categoria && n.Status).OrderByDescending(n => n.NoticiaId).Take(15);

            ViewBag.Noticia = noticia;

            return View(widget);
        }
```

Comment: @FCCDias após comentar esse roteamento funcionou, mas não entendi o porque deste roteamento estar interferindo em outro.

Comment: E para você deixar com o erro e isso servir como base para outros que tiverem o mesmo erro volta o que era

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Modificação:***

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Noticia", "Noticia", new { page = page, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }), PagedListRenderOptions.OnlyShowFivePagesAtATime)
```

Na `Url.Action` se pode colocar o `Controller` e a `Action` que ele pega do roteamento automáticamente, eu me basei que seu **controller** é *Noticia* e sua **action** é *Noticia*, se não for troque na `Url.Action` sendo o primeiro a `Action` e o segundo `Controller`, depois vem o `new` que são a paginação e o filtro ...

**Error:**

*Duplicação de Roteamento*

**O pedido tem encontrado os seguintes tipos de controladores de correspondência:**

- WP_AMERON.Controllers.NoticiaController
- WP_AMERON.Controllers.SalaImprensaController

Existe um roteamento no NoticiaController `[Route("{categoria}/{id}/{titulo}")]` que ta interferindo na suas rotas, porque, as chaves representa variaveis e estavam batendo com as demais rotas que tem esse layout ...

Comment: Fiz como descreveu, mas continua retornando o mesmo erro.

Comment: Pior que não tem, tenho apenas 3 roteamentos nesse controller, segue:

`[Route("sala-de-impresa/noticias/{page?}")]`

`[Route("sala-de-impresa/videos")]`

`[Route("sala-de-impresa/galerias/{page?}")]`

**EDIT**

No controller Noticia não tenho nenhum roteamento!

Comment: Editei com o código dos dois controllers.

Answer (score 1):

O problema estava em um conflito entre uma rota de outro Controller.
A minha rota do Controller `SalaImprensa`:

```
[Route("sala-de-impresa/noticias/{page?}")]
```

Estava conflitando com a rota do Controller `Noticia`:

```
[Route("{categoria}/{id}/{titulo}")]
```

Descobri com a ajuda do @FFCDias e resolvi o problema adicionando um nome antes dos parâmetros da minha rota no Controller `Noticia`:

```
[Route("sala-de-imprensa/{categoria}/{id}/{titulo}")]
```